# Create TYPO3 VHS Bootstrap-Navbar

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, view-helpers

I have a problem with TYPO3 VHS. I want to declare a navbar within my own extension which I created with builder-extension.
It works perfectly, when I look on the source code of my page, everything is like my own html code. But when I click on the 
mother-page of my subpages nothing happens. Like:[My Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QwTb.jpg).
I think I have the wrong TYPO3 settings, because the mother-page also has an href. On my example HTML Code what I created at the beginning, 
all pages had href="#".

`My HTML Code for The Navbar:`

```
<div class="container-fluid farbflussgrau">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                       data-target="#navbarTogglerEU" aria-controls="navbarTogglerEU" aria-expanded="false"
                       aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerEU">
                    <v:page.menu>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
                                <li class="nav-item px-2 {f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: 'dropdown')}">
                                    <f:link.page
                                           pageUid="{item.uid }"
                                           title="{item.title}"
                                           class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: ' dropdown-toggle')}"
                                           additionalAttributes="{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then:
                                                '{data-toggle:\'dropdown\',aria-haspopup:\'true\',aria-expanded:\'false\',href:\'\'}')}">
                                        {item.title}
                                    </f:link.page>
                                    <f:if condition="{item.hasSubPages}">
                                        <v:menu pageUid="{item.uid}">
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <f:for each="{menu}" as="subItem">
                                                    <f:link.page pageUid="{subItem.uid}"
                                                                title="{subItem.title}"
                                                                class="dropdown-item">
                                                        {subItem.title}
                                                    </f:link.page>
                                                </f:for>
                                            </div>
                                        </v:menu>
                                    </f:if>
                                </li>
                            </f:for>
                        </ul>
                    </v:page.menu>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`This is how the sourcecode from my Page looks:` https://pastebin.com/NgG0T0m9?fbclid=IwAR2f6TMuI6Q4tOPHPHw8FFv2Zs827vt9HN2_UI4V1KhHbfLYMQ1DD6zmBjM

And these two images show how the PHPStorm and the Pagetree looks:[Pagetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6Ln.jpg) and [PHPStorm Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zZc6.jpg)

Comment: Please include all relevant code / text directly in your question, rather than linking to it. This will make your question easier to understand, and eliminate the danger of links expiring and future users missing out on relevant info. Also, please use code formatting (e.g. `this type of formatting`) *for code* :)

Comment: Will do it, ty!

Comment: I just filled in the Code for the Navbar. Thesourcecode is only to show that the result is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Possible Solution is to replace

```
<f:link.page
pageUid="{item.uid }"
title="{item.title}"
class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: ' dropdown-toggle')}"
additionalAttributes="{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then:'{data-toggle: \'dropdown\', aria-haspopup:\'true\', aria-expanded:\'false\',href:\'\'}')}">
{item.title}
</f:link.page>
```

with:

```
<a
class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: ' dropdown-toggle')}"
href="{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then:'#', else: '{item.link}')}"
{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then:' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"', else: '')}
pageUid="{item.uid}"
title="{item.title}">
{item.title}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your problem correctly. In case of subpages you would like to have something like a toggle button instead of a link right? To toggle the visibility of the submenu right?

Think about a solution in that way:

```
<v:page.menu>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
        <li class="nav-item px-2 {f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: 'dropdown')}">
            <f:if condition="{item.hasSubPages}">
                <f:then>
                    <button class="togglesubmenu">{item.title}</button>
                    <v:menu pageUid="{item.uid}">
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <f:for each="{menu}" as="subItem">
                                <f:link.page pageUid="{subItem.uid}"
                                             title="{subItem.title}"
                                             class="dropdown-item">
                                    {subItem.title}
                                </f:link.page>
                            </f:for>
                        </div>
                    </v:menu>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <f:link.page
                            pageUid="{item.uid}"
                            title="{item.title}"
                            class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then: ' dropdown-toggle')}"
                            additionalAttributes="{f:if(condition: item.hasSubPages, then:
                        '{data-toggle:\'dropdown\',aria-haspopup:\'true\',aria-expanded:\'false\',href:\'\'}')}">
                        {item.title}
                    </f:link.page>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </li>
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the touch screen handling build in in bootstrap.
In a pure desktop version you can do the flyout of a menu on mouse over, but on a touch screen you have no mouse over. So a touch screen user, who has no mouse and who wants the menu to fly out has to 'click' on the menu entry. This event handling is added by bootstrap javascript to your menu.
This will result in a problem: the normal Link to your page is blocked.

possible solutions:

- the flyout is done with a special icon.
  drawback:

  - be sure the links (eventhandler) are not stacked into each other
  - the touch area of the icon could be very small and users might miss it
- avoid content on pages which have subpages.
  in this way the complete menu entry can be used to handle the flyout.
  drawback:

  - you have empty pages as the pages can be called in other ways (e.g. breadcrumb menu, direct call with id in url). Avoid this by using shortcut pages for every page with subpages. If you want content on such a page create a special first subpage with this content.